# Bootstrap responsive not working when I resize browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am new to bootstrap, I need to convert a static page to bootstrap responsive, Width is 980 px. so I created boot columns according to design and put every div in column with css correction. In normal view everything is fine, But when I re-size window it show like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvwAl.jpg

I have never converted a non-responsive to responsive, please help

Note: What are media queries? Do i have to write css for 3 different sizes?

Comment: We will need to see the code to understand what you may be doing wrong.

Comment: Also, media queries will not be needed for this. Bootstrap abstracts this logic for you.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpPxPV This is a part from page, and thanks in advance

Comment: http://imgur.com/bK2jIjg its a normal view

Answer (score 0):

from twitter bootstrap take the needed template and save the file..and from that take needed js and css of bootstrap..and integrate in the site...

the media query mainly used for responsive are

```
/* CSS Document */
@media (max-width:1200px)
@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px)
@media (max-width:991px)
@media (min-width:991px)
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px)
@media (max-width:767px)
@media (max-width:480px)
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px)
```

Answer (score 0):

Media query is missing.

```
        @media screen(max-width:800px) { 
            body { font-size:0.8em; }
            img { width:300px; }
        }
```

For the better understanding go through the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/doxaras/fjrWn/2/)